# How to plot bars against percent and annotate with the value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I couldn't expand bars height to their percentage how can I do that? I'm getting confused...

I don't want to see the percentages of the bars, I want the values (40,40,40,40,40,33,17).

I want 7 bars with height of their percentage, but containers on bars should have their value name. For example n=40 in my problem; First bar has the value of 40. So this bars top should at %100 level, but container must wrote as 40.

Also another example; last (Tiktok bar) bar has the value of 17 so container should say 17 but the bar should be at the height of %42.5

### Sample DataFrame and Imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

plt.figure(figsize=(18,11),dpi=100)
sns.set_theme (style="whitegrid", palette="tab20b")

x_ekseni= ['İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları']
Website= [40]
Twitter= [40]
Facebook= [40]
Instagram= [40]
Youtube= [40]
Linkedin= [33]
Tiktok= [17]

index=x_ekseni

df = pd.DataFrame({'Website': Website,
               'Twitter': Twitter,
               'Facebook': Facebook,
               'Instagram': Instagram,
               'Youtube': Youtube,
               'Linkedin': Linkedin,
               'Tiktok': Tiktok}, index=index)
```

#### `df`

```
                               Website  Twitter  Facebook  Instagram  Youtube  Linkedin  Tiktok
İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları       40       40        40         40       40        33      17
```

### Plot

```py
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=False,edgecolor='white',width = 2.5,linewidth=0.5)

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:

    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    col = c.get_label()

    labels = df[col].replace(0, '')

    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', fontweight='bold', color='white',fontsize=10)

plt.title("İstanbul'daki Belediyelerin Sosyal Medya Kullanımı", fontsize=11, fontweight=0,        color="black", loc="center")

ax.set_ylabel("İldeki Tüm Belediyeler İçinde Yüzde (n=40)", fontsize= 10)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())

plt.xticks(rotation=0,fontsize=8)
plt.yticks(rotation=0,fontsize=8)
plt.ylim(0,100)

ax.legend(frameon=True, fontsize=8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**
- Note the plot in the OP is a single group of bars, which is why there's only one tick.
- In order to have the bars be the height of their respective percent value, calculate and add a new column with the percent value, plot the bars with the new column, and pass the actual values to the `labels=` parameter in `.bar_label`.

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# test dataframe
data = {'Website': [40], 'Twitter': [40], 'Facebook': [40], 'Instagram': [40], 'Youtube': [40], 'Linkedin': [33], 'Tiktok': [17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları'])

# transpose df from a wide to a long form
df = df.T

# add a percent column
df['per'] = df.div(df.sum()).mul(100).round(2)
```

#### `df`

```
           İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları   per
Website                               40  16.0
Twitter                               40  16.0
Facebook                              40  16.0
Instagram                             40  16.0
Youtube                               40  16.0
Linkedin                              33  13.2
Tiktok                                17   6.8
```

### Plot using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) with [`kind='bar'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

```py
# plot percent column 
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', y='per', rot=0, figsize=(10, 7), ylabel='', legend=False)

# add the annotations; there's only 1 container of 7 artists
# iterating through the containers is only necessary for grouped or stacked bars, which have multiple containers
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df['İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları'].replace(0, ''), label_type='center', fontweight='bold', color='white', fontsize=10)

ax.set_title("İstanbul'daki Belediyelerin Sosyal Medya Kullanımı", fontsize=11, fontweight=0, color="black", loc="center")

ax.set_ylabel("İldeki Tüm Belediyeler İçinde Yüzde (n=40)", fontsize= 10)
ax.set_xlabel(df.columns[0], fontsize= 10)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.PercentFormatter())

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
_ = ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

[image]

### Plot using [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

# plot df, but the index must be reset
ax = sns.barplot(data=df.reset_index(), x='index', y='per')

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df['İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları'].replace(0, ''), label_type='center', fontweight='bold', color='white', fontsize=10)

ax.set_title("İstanbul'daki Belediyelerin Sosyal Medya Kullanımı", fontsize=11, fontweight=0, color="black", loc="center")

ax.set_ylabel("İldeki Tüm Belediyeler İçinde Yüzde (n=40)", fontsize= 10)
ax.set_xlabel(df.columns[0], fontsize= 10)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.PercentFormatter())

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
_ = ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

[image]

### Note

- Updated based on additional information added to the OP from a comment, where the percent is calculated against a specific value, `n=40`, use the following to calculate the `'per'` column.
- Nothing else in the previous code needs to change.

```py
# an arbitrary value
n = 40
df['per'] = df.div(n, axis=0).mul(100).round(2)

# or

# the max value in the column
df['per'] = df.div(df.iloc[:, 0].max(), axis=0).mul(100).round(2)
```

```
           İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları    per
Website                               40  100.0
Twitter                               40  100.0
Facebook                              40  100.0
Instagram                             40  100.0
Youtube                               40  100.0
Linkedin                              33   82.5
Tiktok                                17   42.5
```

[image: plotted with pandas.DataFrame.plot]

[image: plotted with seaborn.barplot]

Answer (score 0):

To display the percentage values on top of each bar in your stacked bar chart, you can use the bar_label function provided by matplotlib.

```
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, labels=[f'{h:.0f}%' if h > 0 else '' for h in container.datavalues], label_type='edge')
```

Complete code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

plt.figure(figsize=(18,11),dpi=100)
sns.set_theme (style="whitegrid", palette="tab20b")

x_ekseni= ['İlgili Sosyal Medya Hesapları']
Website= [40]
Twitter= [40]
Facebook= [40]
Instagram= [40]
Youtube= [40]
Linkedin= [33]
Tiktok= [17]

index=x_ekseni

df = pd.DataFrame({'Website': Website,
               'Twitter': Twitter,
               'Facebook': Facebook,
               'Instagram': Instagram,
               'Youtube': Youtube,
               'Linkedin': Linkedin,
               'Tiktok': Tiktok}, index=index)

ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=False, edgecolor='white', width=2.5, linewidth=0.5)

for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, labels=[f'{h:.0f}%' if h > 0 else '' for h in container.datavalues], label_type='edge')

plt.title("İstanbul'daki Belediyelerin Sosyal Medya Kullanımı", fontsize=11, fontweight=0, color="black", loc="center")

ax.set_ylabel("İldeki Tüm Belediyeler İçinde Yüzde (n=40)", fontsize=10)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.xticks(rotation=0, fontsize=8)
plt.yticks(rotation=0, fontsize=8)
plt.ylim(0, 100)

ax.legend(frameon=True, fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```